# Unable to Login to Wok on Fedora Server 27 - Python and PAM

Tags: fedora, python, pam

I just setup WOK and can't login via my root uname/pwd. I found a ticket on Github with a "solution" but I have no idea how to implement it.

Does anybody have an idea how to translate this into usable fix?

```
--- /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wok/auth.py.org    2018-05-18 18:56:52.948726704 +0100
+++ /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wok/auth.py        2018-05-18 18:57:15.843333455 +0100
@@ -145,7 +145,7 @@
             debug("User %s is not allowed to run sudo" % self.name)

     @staticmethod
-    def authenticate(username, password, service="passwd"):
+    def authenticate(username, password, service="system-auth"):
         '''Returns True if authenticate is OK via PAM.'''
         def _auth(result):
             def _pam_conv(auth, query_list, userData=None):
```

Source: https://github.com/kimchi-project/kimchi/issues/1232#issuecomment-390288343

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This file is in "unified diff" format. Lines starting with `-` are replaced by those starting with `+`. The `@@ ... @@` section header describes where in the file the subsequent few lines are to be found. You would use the `patch` command to apply the changes from this file. Assuming you've saved that snippet as `patchfile` you could run this:

```
patch -b <patchfile
```

The `-b` flag tells the `patch` program to make a backup of the file before it attempts to change it.

Alternatively, since by visual inspection the only difference is that `passwd` has been replaced by `system-auth`, you could simply edit the file using your favourite editor.

```
vi +148 /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wok/auth.py
```

Comment: Good to know! I figured out the - was removed and the + was changes, but didn't realize it was formatted to be run as a patch. I ended up just using sed but now I will know if I see this format again.

Answer (score 0):

```
cat /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wok/auth.py  | grep service=
sed -i -e 's/passwd/system-auth/g' /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wok/auth.py 
cat /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wok/auth.py  | grep service=
service wokd restart
```